# What is the difference between witness node and ordinary node

Tags: node, consensus, full-node

A DApp developer does not need to run the entire EOS blockchain, if so why would anyone want to be a witness node(full node?) since they are not part of the DPoS consensus. Aren't all transactions performed by Block Producers, does this mean that the only thing a node does is send and receive actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The philosophy behind DPoS is that, even though only a small set of nodes (in case of EOS, 21 Active BPs) are elected to produce blocks, every full node keeps an entire copy of block data & state data.

So basically:

- Every full node will validate the incoming blocks, checking signatures for transactions, checking contract execution results, checking if the producer of the incoming block is the elected BP, etc. --- a lot of things that prevent the chain to corrupt.
- Every full node could provide READ access to the chain data. As every node has a complete copy, every node could response to read access like getTableRows directly. That's like a whole decentralized CDN.
- Of course broadcasting transactions for users. That's like WRITE access to the chain data.

Comment: Lets say some one owns 1% of EOS tokens. Would that mean they could use their 1% stake to acquire 1% network bandwidth provided by the 21 block producers or 1% network bandwidth of all full nodes(incl. Block producers)?

Comment: @DEVANABOINA The name of the "network bandwidth" resource can be misleading. In practice, the network bandwidth cost is just the number of bytes required to encode a transaction. Network bandwidth can be seen as a parameter of blockchain as a whole, and not of individual nodes transferring bytes between each other.

Comment: @Gassa Ok thanks for the clarification. my comment wasn't specific to network bandwidth but any resource that an EOS token can claim a portion of. My sub-question still stands. Do EOS tokens represents a stake in the resources provided by the Block producers only or all full nodes(including block producers & witness nodes)? I find this question to be a followup to my original question but if it is more appropriate to post it separately then i will do that

Comment: @DEVANABOINA What I'm trying to say is this. Staked EOS tokens reserve the right to use a certain amount of _EOS blockchain_ resources. When you decide to use these resources, you implicitly use the actual physical resources of every node maintaining the current state of the blockchain. If a node maintains the current state of the blockchain, it's irrelevant whether it's a block producer or some personal node: it will have to process the transaction.